# Best practice for invoke-ing a tool that internally calls `exec`?

Tags: python-click

pipenv uses click, and uses click's [invoke](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/api/#click.Context.invoke) method [in its unit test suite](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/9d532123d1c6d7e8067bd7b9e374f48f54e142d6/tests/integration/conftest.py#L376) to test itself.

This does not work great when unit testing the `pipenv run` command, which [internally uses `execve`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/9d532123d1c6d7e8067bd7b9e374f48f54e142d6/pipenv/core.py#L2670-L2674). In the context of a single threaded test run this means our test runner (`pytest`) process gets completely replaced by whatever we're `exec`-ing, and the test suite immediately and silently exits.

(This bug on the pipenv issue tracker talks about this in more detail: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4909)

Is there a best practice for how to handle situations like this with click? Should we not be using click's `invoke` at all, and instead using regular old `subprocess`? Or perhaps `invoke` could optionally run the command in a subprocess rather than the current process? Or maybe there's a best practice for cli apps that use click to detect if they're being run via `invoke` and just be careful *not* to do anything in the `exec` family (this is basically what pipenv does right now: if the `CI` env var is set, then `pipenv run` triggers a subprocess rather than using `execve`).